# What is the alternative for the depricated tref?

Tags: svg

I have been reading into to svg spec a bit. I read about the `tref`-element https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#text-TRefElement. Most of you will probably know that `tref` will be / is depricated. That led me to wonder how to do the same thing now. It shouldn't be too hard, but I can't really find anything on the topic. I am also curious about the reasoning behind depricating the `tref`. But that would just be a 'fun fact'. So in short:

- What is the alternative for tref?
- Why has tref been depricated?

**svg**

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <text id="ReferencedText">
      Referenced character data
    </text>
  </defs>
  <text x="100" y="200" font-size="45" fill="red" >
    <tref href="#ReferencedText"/>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Put the text inline. Hard to implement.

Comment: @Robert Longson I can imagine that it would be easier to put text somewhere seperately for more complex svg's so it would be easier to change texts in the future. That said it might be part of the reasoning in depricating it.

Comment: Nothing's stoping you from writing an SVG generator that works that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something similar with a little bit of Javascript.

```js
$("text[tref]").each(function(index, textElem) {
  $text = $(textElem);
  ref = $text.attr("tref");
  refText = $(ref).text();
  $text.text(refText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <defs>
    <text id="ReferencedText">Referenced character data</text>
    <text id="OtherText">What magic is this?</text>
  </defs>
  <text x="50" y="100" font-size="20" fill="red" tref="#ReferencedText"/>
  <text x="50" y="150" font-size="25" fill="green" tref="#OtherText"/>
</svg>
```

**Pure JS version**

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("text[tref]");
elems.forEach(function(element) {
  tref = element.getAttribute("tref");
  refText = document.querySelector(tref).textContent;
  element.textContent = refText;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <defs>
    <text id="ReferencedText">Referenced character data</text>
    <text id="OtherText">What magic is this?</text>
  </defs>
  <text x="50" y="100" font-size="20" fill="red" tref="#ReferencedText"/>
  <text x="50" y="150" font-size="25" fill="green" tref="#OtherText"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This seems to be a pretty smart solution, that 'replaces' the old behavior. A pure js solution, without jQuery, would be more reusable, tough. I expected there would be a more obvious solution or alternative, since they deprecated the element. Guess I was wrong there. Thx for the answer ;).

Comment: I used jQuery for arbitrary reasons. It could easily be done with pure JS also.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same situation and upon further reading I tested the following and it worked as tref used to work:

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <text id="Text1">The text to be shown</text>
    </defs>


    <use xlink:href="#Text1" x="560" y="850" style="font-family: Arial;fill:#000000; font-size:28px;">
</svg>
```

Comment: When I copypaste your example (and add a closing tag to `<use>`) your code in JS-Fiddle doesn't visibly output anything: https://jsfiddle.net/w0Lz6126/

Comment: My bad. It's working but the x and y values are too high for the viewport^^ Simply change those to like x=10 and y=10 and you should see the text.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it's idiomatic SVG while the current accepted answer uses something outside SVG.